# JPA search query using Criteria Builder for multiple columns

Tags: jpa, ejb, jpql, java-ee-6, criteriaquery

I am trying to make a universal search for my entity with criteria builder where a given text is matched with all the columns in the entity.

```
String likeSearchText = "%" + searchText + "%";
List<Customer> searchedCustomers = null;
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery query = builder.createQuery(Customer.class);
Root <Customer> root = query.from(Customer.class);
ArrayList<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
conditions.add(builder.like(root.<String>get("firstName"), likeSearchText));
conditions.add(builder.like(root.<String>get("lastName"), likeSearchText));
conditions.add(builder.like(root.<String>get("middleName"), likeSearchText));
conditions.add(builder.like(root.<String>get("companyName"), likeSearchText));
conditions.add(builder.like(root.<String>get("industry"), likeSearchText));
query.where(builder.or(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[conditions.size()])));
query.select(root);
searchedCustomers = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
return searchedCustomers;
```

When I run this method I always get an empty list. I tried changing the `like` to `notLike` and that works perfectly fine by giving me a list containing elements which are not like the given search text so I am really confused as to what's wrong with my `like` method.
Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Comment: Actually my answer might not be very helpful but instead have you checked that the letter casing is the same, for example? Tried to use to lowerCase() or so?

Comment: I can't see that anything is wrong. So I'd recommend to turn on sql logging and hav a look at the generated Statements. In case you're using eclipseLink this can be done with entries in persistence.xml: <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE" /> <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" /> <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="JavaLogger" />

Comment: @pirho Yeah the string argument passed to this method is already lower cased.

Comment: @frank Thanks! I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems when I made some testing and had entities with the same (simple)name in the classpath. So for example there were entities like:

```
org.example.one.Customer
org.example.two.Customer
```

If you do not have explicitly set different table names like:

```
package org.example.one;
@Entity("customer_one")
public class Customer { ...
```

and

```
package org.example.two;
@Entity("customer_two")
public class Customer { ...
```

hibernate might:

- mix stuff in the same table in db
- try to find field from wrong table when constructing the query

Also I thibk you do not need this:

```
query.select(root);
```

Comment: I do have one other class with the same name but the packages for both the classes are different and the other class is not even an entity. Only one Customer class is of type entity. Would hibernate still mix those two classes?

Comment: The package does not matter if there is a situation that two entities point to same db-table in my experience. But I do not see it possible that Hibernate would mix entity and non entity since the non entioty does not point to db table. But can not be sure.